# Possible bug, using not operator in search

Tags: bug, search, new-nav

I was trying to search for questions tagged [styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/styling), but not [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) I used the not operator like so:

> [styling] -[css]

Initially it returned the expected result, as in a brief flash of questions tagged styling and not css, but when the search results finish loading I get the "that's a miss" message.

Steps to recreate:

1. Type `[styling] -[css]` in the search field in the upper right corner.
2. Press enter
3. Wait...

If it matters I'm on a Windows 10 machine, using both Firefox 42.0 and Chrome 46

Comment: Windows 8.1 and Chome 46, no repo.  The search returned the results and did not get anything else.

Comment: Are you using the new search style (the one you have to opt in through your profile)?

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this behavior, but only on select search boxes.  If I use the form `[styling] and not [css]`, it seems to work alright, but *only* if I use tabs to filter this out.

Comment: @Makoto yes, I'm using the new search style.

Comment: Win 7/Chrome 46 - no repo.

Comment: OS X 10.10, Safari 8, results show as expected *on the main site*. On Meta, it switches to `[design] not` (New Nav)

Comment: Seeing this consistently on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-avd%20not%20avd?mode=all or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-avd%20not%20android?mode=all the page loads results first then shows "That's a miss"

Comment: Recurrence of [this MSE bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259915/hard-to-exclude-tags-in-search-for-new-nav)?  Only thing is that was marked as `status-completed`.

Comment: @ryanyuyu `Status-not-so-complete-as-we-thought`